# How to print filename in awk?

Tags: bash, awk

I would like to print filename and then the value of $7 in the cycle. What is wrong please? with `'"i"'`

```
for i in r*; do
    awk 'FNR == 2 {print '"i"', $7}' r* > out
done
```

OUTPUT after advise

```
fdfadfasdfa     0.00775                 0.00644                 6298
dsafdsfsaf      0.00705                 0.00574                 14173
dasfdsafdafd        0.00716                 0.00597                 22948
dafadsafdafsdf      0.00859                 0.00679                 5210
dafadsfsa       0.00705                 0.00576                 11098
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you please try following. You need not to use `for` loop for it.

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t\t"} FNR==2{print FILENAME, $7}' r*  | column -t > out
```

In case you have GNU `awk` you can use `nextfile` to save many cycles and directly jump to next file once condition met like:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t\t"} FNR==2{print FILENAME, $7; nextfile}' r*  | column -t > out
```

To set `\t\t` as tab separator for output set `OFS` in `BEGIN` section. Add `| column -t` in output to get it correct format of TAB.

Remove `BEGIN{OFS="\t\t"}` in case it is NOT required since `column` command is added(OP asked for TAB in output so that was added for it).

Answer (score 2):

Since you're relying on bash to supply `$i` you need to include a dollar sign. Also the single and double quotes should be swapped. Awk needs to see the double quotes so they need to be inside the single quotes.

```
for i in r*; do
    awk 'FNR == 2 {print "'$i'", $7}' r* > out
done
```

Note that this isn't safe if `$i` could contain special characters. It's best not to expand bash variables directly inside awk scripts. You get quoting problems, whitespace problems; it's a ticking time bomb.

It's better to use `-v` to pass bash variables to awk. It's safer and it avoids the quoting and escaping problem to boot. You can just write `i`, simple as that.

```
for i in r*; do
    awk -v i="$i" 'FNR == 2 {print i, $7}' r* > out
done
```

Comment: Thank you and why the forst column of filenames is not different? I have the same file on all lines

Comment: See @RavinderSingh13's answer.